# input multiple files all containing diffrent lists in python

Tags: python

filename.txt contains

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

The python file has the following lines:

```
my_file = open("filename.txt", "r")
content_list = my_file.readlines()
print (content_list)
```

when following the above I get ['a = [1, 2, 3]'] as an output
How to input the the list in python so that I can use 'a' in the code.

Thank you.
Basem

Comment: This is too broad of a topic for a Stack Overflow question. You need to write code that interprets the file's contents, according to the file's format. This requires that you actually have a format in mind. You should choose something that makes your life easier. "Make it look as if it were Python source code" generally does *not* make your life easier. Instead, research standard formats like JSON and CSV, which have built-in standard library support.

Comment: If you really want to use `a` in a file, try `ast.literal_eval`. But I think it is a `X-Y problem`, what you really need is `[1,2,3]` which is the value of `a`, not `a`. So you can change the file to CSV or JSON format then use `Python` to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rather that naming the file .txt, name it .py, Once you have done it, you can access the variable by import the file in the beginning of the program.

If you dont want to make all the above mess you can remove the a variable 'a' from the txt file and leave the list like this:-,

in filename.txt:-

```
[1,2,3]
```

and then in your main .py file, you can assign the readline to a variable say 'a'. You can now access the variable in other parts of your program. It goes something like this:-

in .py file:-

```
with open ('fiename.txt','r') as f #using a context manager(its better)
    a = f.read()
print(a)
```

Since the open and read command actually reads it as string rather than a list or any other data type, you will get your output, where the above code will generate the following output:-

```
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Either [exec()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) the content of the file after reading it, but it's generally not recommended to exec arbitrary code like this. Or you can [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement) the file (need to change it to .py).